# How to create a JSON Object from a query in Laravel 10?

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-10

I need to return a JSON like this
`

```
{
        "title": "Nueva noticia",
        "category": "Deportes",
        "body": "Nueva noticia de deportes",
        "image_name": "Imagen",
        "publication_date": "2024-02-16 00:00:00",
        "id": 1,
        "creator":{
           name": "Benjamin Camacho",
          "email": "benjamin.camacho@email.com"
         }
}
```

but I don´t how to specify the object creator

This is my query and I trying using and SQL Alias

```
 $noticias = DB::table('blogs')
            ->leftJoin('category', 'blogs.category_id', '=', 'category.id')
            ->leftJoin('users', 'blogs.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->select('blogs.title','category.name as category','blogs.body','blogs.image_name','blogs.publication_date', 'blogs.id','users.name as creator::name', 'users.email as creator/email')
            ->get();
        return $noticias ;
```

Comment: Take a look at [eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships) I think the default JSON output for a 1 - many relationship is like that

Comment: What is the current value of `$noticias`?